# IOS caseInsensitiveCompare

Tags: ios

I have the code below that compares two values and returns if match is found, the problem is that it is case-sensitive, I googled around and found the method caseInsensitiveCompare, please help me run this program with caseInsensitiveCompare method, I am lost.

```
NSString *listOfnames = @"person, person1, person2, person3";
NSString *name = @"person2";

NSRange match = [listOfnames rangeOfString:name];

 if(match.location  == NSNotFound ){
    NSLog(@"Person not found!");
}else{
    NSLog(@"Found you");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `rangeOfString:options:` rendition with the `NSCaseInsensitiveSearch` option:

```
NSString *listOfnames = @"person, person1, person2, person3";
NSString *name = @"PERSON2";

NSRange match = [listOfnames rangeOfString:name options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

if(match.location  == NSNotFound ){
    NSLog(@"Person not found!");
}else{
    NSLog(@"Found you");
}
```